# Binomial Coefficients proof

Tags: binomial-coefficients

[image]

I tried various methods, but I don't know how to proceed further, because I am fairly new to this chapter.
[image]

Please hep!

Comment: The resulting equation can be achieved by taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$. Are you allowed to do that?

Comment: I am.But, which equation should I differentiate?

Comment: Should I differentiate the identity/expansion of (1+x)^n?

Comment: Yes, differentiate the given equation $(1+x)^n=....$. @JamilAhmed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If differentiation is not mandatory,

for $n\ge r>0,$
$$r\binom nr=r\cdot\dfrac{n\cdot(n-1)!}{\{n-(r-1)\}!r\cdot (r-1)!}=n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

$$\implies\sum_{r=1}^nr\binom nrx^{r-1}=n\sum_{r=1}^n\binom{n-1}{r-1}x^{r-1}=n(1+x)^{n-1}$$